# Ionic: Schedule a Function Call

Tags: ionic3

I need to be able to schedule a function execution at a specific date and time. My current project states that I have an application running on a tablet 24/7. On a specific date and time (ex: 2018-09-01 14:00.00) I need to execute this function once.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your use case. I see 2 different ways of doing that:

1. Schedule the time where the function is executed by using `setTimeout()`
2. Add a `setInterval()` that gets executed every second or minute, and check if there is anything to be executed.

I would prefer the first way if you only have one or very few things that need to be executed. You can simply calculate the time difference (in milliseconds) between now and when the function should be executed and then call `setTimeout()` with that time.

If you want to schedule many functions during the day, you might want to use solution 2 and execute all functions that should have happened within the last x seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could use rxjs `Observable.timer()`.  An example below.

```js
//What time is it now?
let now = new Date();

//Get timer fire date (Or use a date string like this>> '2018-09-04T08:26:00');
let timeDateString = new Date(now.getTime() + 60000).toString();
let timerDate = new Date(timeDateString);

//Get diff
let timerFireMillis = timerDate.valueOf() - now.valueOf();

//Prove it
console.log(`now: ${now}`);
console.log(`timer: ${timerDate}`);
console.log(`diff: ${timerFireMillis} millis`);

//Fire the timer with the diff calculated above
//May want to keep track of this fella, and unsubscribe in certain cases
const mySubscription = rxjs.timer(timerFireMillis).subscribe(() => {
  console.log(`I just fired at ${new Date()}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.2.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ionic 2/3 you could leverage local notifications. Schedule event with it and then leverage .on(eventName) method that can trigger callback etc.

See here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/